# Laravel Eloquent Polymorphic Scope latest first item

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, scopes, has-many-polymorphs

Good day,

I'm a bit stuck here with fetching latest item using Laravel scopes and Eloquent Polymorphic One-to-Many relationship.

Given:

- I'm using latest version of Laravel 6.x.
- I have two models: `Website` and `Status`.
- `Status` model is reusable and can be used with other models.
- Each website has multiple statuses.
- Every time status is changed a new record is created in DB.
- Active website status is the latest one in the DB.

Websites model:

```
class Website extends Model
{
    public function statuses()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Statuses::class, 'stateable');
    }

    public function scopePending($query)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('statuses', function ($query) {
            $query->getByStatusCode('pending');
        });
    }
}
```

Statuses model:

```
class Statuses extends Model
{
    public function stateable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function scopeGetByStatusCode($query, $statusCode)
    {
        return $query->where('status_code', $statusCode)->latest()->limit(1);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call:

```
Website::pending()->get();
```

**The `pending()` scope will return all websites that have ever got a `pending` status assigned to them, and not the websites that have currently active `pending` status (eg. latest status).**

Here is the query that is returned with `DB::getQueryLog()`

```
select * from `websites` 
    where exists 
    (
        select * from `statuses` 
        where `websites`.`id` = `statuses`.`stateable_id` 
        and `statuses`.`stateable_type` = "App\\Models\\Website" 
        and `status_code` = 'pending' 
        order by `created_at` desc limit 1
    ) 
and `websites`.`deleted_at` is null
```

What is the right way of obtaining `pending` websites using scope with polymorphic one-to-many relation?

Similar issue is descried here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/polymorphic-relations-and-scope

Thanks.

Comment: The raw query is not quite right, it got to be `websites.id` instead of `website.id`.

Comment: Good catch, but it's just a typo since I have changed some wording there. The SQL is purely an example output.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after doing some research, I have stumbled across this article: https://nullthoughts.com/development/2019/10/08/dynamic-scope-on-latest-relationship-in-laravel/

Solution turned out to be quite *eloquent* (sorry for bad pun):

```
protected function scopePending($query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('statuses', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', function ($sub) {
            $sub->from('statuses')
                ->selectRaw('max(id)')
                ->whereColumn('statuses.stateable_id', 'websites.id');
         })->where('status_code', 'pending');
    });
}
```